# reg.ru - однопоточный Flask

Tags: многопоточность, flask, хостинг

Разрабатываю сайт на Flask, python3.8. Столкнулся с проблемой: сайт однопоточный (все запросы обрабатывает один main thread, проверял через threading.current_thread()), несмотря на то, что Flask в обычном режиме поддерживает многопоточность. Устанавливал Flask по [статье на reg ru](https://help.reg.ru/hc/ru/articles/4408047458449-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-Flask-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3). Локально на компе всё работает в многопоточке, как и нужно. Создаю application = Flask(), то есть не указывая доп параметры

Контроля над непосредственным запуском скрипта (в том числе над application.run()) у меня, видимо, нет - сайт запускается автоматически, судя по всему, через скрипт /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py, который уже вызывает passenger-wsgi.py из туториала. Но в wsgi-loader.py есть опция env[wsgi.multithread]=False, и этот файл, естественно, защищён от записи (как лежащий в /usr/share) - можно ли это как-то обойти?

Comment: Но вообще `Flask` вроде и есть однопоточный. Чтобы он стал многопоточным его надо сверху во что-то более продвинутое оборачивать, насколько я помню.

Comment: Накидал простой пример (https://pastebin.com/iJX7wcrM) - можно запустить, зайти с одного компа с нескольких вкладок одновременно на /increment, и время ожидания будет примерно 5 секунд в сумме, а не 5 * число_открытых_вкладок. И будет выводиться новое имя треда каждый раз. На reg.ru же и время ожидания суммируется, и выводится MAIN_THREAD всегда

Comment: А попробуйте вот этот признак глянуть https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Request.is_multiprocess.html

Comment: Вернее этот. Ну или оба посмотрите https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Request.is_multithread.html?highlight=multithread#flask.Request.is_multithread В обоих окружениях. Что там покажет и что здесь.

Comment: Кажется, всё решилось - действительно, в облаке просто была отключена многопоточность (в том числе и флаг Request) - просто из-за тарифа, на хостинге не дают возможность именно фласку создавать новые треды (то есть да, wsgi специально настроен на один тред). Причём самостоятельно создать треды получается. Надо перейти с хостинга на VPS или Dedicated server. Жаль, что reg.ru нигде не пишет об ограничении на потоки в веб приложении... Всё равно благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос и за комментарии! У самого reg.ru + flask, буду иметь ввиду.

Только я не совсем понял. "Самостоятельно создать треды получается" - следует ли из этого, что можно сделать вручную многопоточный сервер, или нет?